YGuard cannot find a mapping for java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory during the remapping process
Yguard-4.1.0.
Application compiled with java 21 compiler but  source and  target compatibility  are set to  17.
Its working if both source and target are 1.8.
task obfuscate(dependsOn: jar) {
doLast {
    copy {
        from "${project.buildDir}/libs/abc.jar"
        into "${project.buildDir}/libs/non-obfuscated"
    }
    
    ant.taskdef(name: 'yguard', classname: 'com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask', classpath: configurations.yguard.asPath)
    
    ant.yguard() {
        inoutpair(in: "${project.buildDir}/libs/abc.jar", out: "${project.buildDir}/libs/xyz.jar")
        
        externalclasses {                
            pathelement(path: configurations.compile.asPath)
        }

        rename(logfile: "${project.buildDir}/renamelog.xml") {
            property(name: "error-checking", value: "pedantic")
            property(name: "language-conformity", value: "compatible")
            property(name: "naming-scheme", value: "best")

            adjust(replaceName: "true") {
                include(name: "**/*.properties")
            }

            keep() {
                'class'(classes:"public", fields:"public", methods:"public") {
                    patternset() {
                        include(name: "com.org.prod.abc.*")
                        exclude(name: "com.org.prod.abc.testfile")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}

Caused by: : yGuard encountered an IO problem!
        at com.yworks.yguard.ObfuscatorTask.execute(ObfuscatorTask.java:1254)
        at com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask.execute(YGuardTask.java:118)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:103) 
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:656)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:637)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: An error ('No mapping found for: Class java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory') occured during the remapping! See the log!)
        at com.yworks.yguard.obf.GuardDB.remapTo(GuardDB.java:528)
        at com.yworks.yguard.ObfuscatorTask.execute(ObfuscatorTask.java:1225)

Tried following steps.
Added following in the below task

pathelement(location: System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar")

include(name: "java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory")


 ant.yguard() {
        inoutpair(in: "${project.buildDir}/libs/abc.jar", out: "${project.buildDir}/libs/xyz.jar")
        
        externalclasses {                
            pathelement(path: configurations.compile.asPath)
            pathelement(location: System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar")
        }

        rename(logfile: "${project.buildDir}/renamelog.xml") {
            property(name: "error-checking", value: "pedantic")
            property(name: "language-conformity", value: "compatible")
            property(name: "naming-scheme", value: "best")

            adjust(replaceName: "true") {
                include(name: "**/*.properties")
            }

            keep() {
                'class'(classes:"public", fields:"public", methods:"public") {
                    patternset() {
                        include(name: "com.org.prod.abc.*")
                        exclude(name: "com.org.prod.abc.testfile")
                        include(name: "java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Any help highly appreciated.
